# How To Replace Hashtags with HTML Anchor in Python/Django?

Tags: python, regex, django

`message = "@me this is nice. @you: let me #help you. #anyone> #Python, #All."`

`message.split()` gives "

`['@me', 'this', 'is', 'nice.', '@you:', 'let', 'me', '#help', 'you.', '#anyone>', '#Python,', '#All.']`

But what I want is

`['@me', 'this', 'is', 'nice.', '@you', 'let', 'me', '#help', 'you.', '#anyone', '#Python', '#All']`. Without the `:`, `.`, `>` or any other symbol. I just want **words** alone.

`startswith('#')` should return

`['#help', '#anyone', '#Python', #All]` and the `hashtag_links` will then return

`["<a href='hashtags\help'>#help</a>", "<a href='hashtags\anyone'>#anyone</a>", ...]`

What I want to do is to be able to replace hashtags in `message` with their equivalent in `hashtag_links` so that they can be clickable when rendered in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
[\s.:>,]
```

You can split by this.Use `re.split`.Remove the blank groups.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/11

Comment: @Yax `re.split(r"[\s.:>,]",message)`

Comment: This works but how do I replace it back to the original message? And isn't there a more simpler way to do this without listing the symbols?

Comment: @Yax use a variable. `x=re.split(r"[\s.:>,]",message)`. now use `x` for further operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily with list comprehensions:

```
mylist = [i.rstrip(":;") for i in message.split() if i] # remove blanks
hashtagged = [i for i in mylist if i.startswith("#")]
```